# How to change SQL Server 2008 authentication mode?

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL Server 2008 and I want to check/change its authentication mode. Now I've seen several ways to do so in the web using *SQL Server Management* but I don't have that..

Is there any way to do so using built-in *Windows*/*SQL Server 2008* tools?

Comment: I which way you want to do that can you post screen shots? I'm pretty sure that people are not understanding your question clearly.

Comment: There is a simple way to do this is File>Connection Object explorer and you can change your authenticaton.

Comment: @avrik Where can I find File>Connection Object explorer ?

Comment: When you open the SQL Sever at that time you can set the authentication mode before clicking `connect`. If you don't do that then the easy way to connect the SQL Sever and go to File menu and click on `Connection Object Explorer`. If still you have problem to do this tell me I'll upload screen shots.

Comment: Basically there are two type of authentication which one you want to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the authentication mode can be determined/changed by checking the value of a registry key.

Within Management Studio, if I change my local database from Windows only to Mixed and script the change to a new query window, it generates the following query.

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite 
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
,   N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer'
,   N'LoginMode'
,   REG_DWORD
,   2
```

If you do not have SSMS installed, you might still have [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) installed. Invocation would be something like

`sqlcmd.exe -S MyServer -d master -Q "EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2"`

You might need to use xp_regwrite vs xp_instance_regwrite depending on whether you have multiple instances on a server (my example does).  This article on [sswug](http://www.sswug.org/articles/viewarticle.aspx?id=21892) shows it using xp_regwrite.

If you don't even have sqlcmd/osql etc installed, you can edit the registry directly but be certain to back it up before making changes.

Finally, the instance needs to be restarted before the change takes effect.